# read & write properties file in gradle build script

Tags: groovy, gradle

I am new in **Gradle** build script. Say, I have two properties files in my file system. I would like to read all fields in the two properties files & write to a new properties file. How to achieve this in gradle?

For example, **file1.properties** contains:

```
name = John
age = 30
```

**file2.properties** contains:

```
gender = male
```

I would like my build script read all the fields in two files & write to a new file in a different location. That's **new file** contains:

```
name = John
age = 30
gender = male
```

How to do it in gradle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this simple script in groovy:

```
def targetFile = new File("<combinedFileWithPath>")

// Create directory structure of the target file before writing the file
targetFile.parentFile.mkdirs()

// Create target file using writer
targetFile.withWriter { w ->

    // List of input files
    ["<firstFilePath>", "<secondFilePath", "<thirdFilePath>"].each { f ->

        // Use reader on current file
        new File(f).withReader { r ->

            // Append data from each file to the writer of the combined file
            w << r << "\n"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gradle complains that No such file or directory combinedFile.properties. Why gradle complains it? Sure there is no such file, that's the file it should generate. Any ideas?

Comment: That is strange. Is the path you're writing the new file to writable? Also, make sure that the folders up to the file path do exist (the file need not exist, but the folder structure should be present).

Comment: Edited my answer to create parent folder structure before file creation.